# finding a text in a word and replace it with table

Tags: asp.net, office-interop, com-interop

I use Asp.Net and Interop.Word.dll for reading a word document. I need a thing like this. I have keywords in word. I find it and replace it with a table. I made this process to replace with a text. It is ok. Now I try to replace a string with a table. Can anyone make a thing like this?
Thanks in advance.

I try a code like below.

```
   foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range tmpRange in doc.StoryRanges)
        {

            object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            object findme = "##tablo1##";

            //object replaceme = misyonval;
            tmpRange.Application.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
            tmpRange.Application.Selection.Find.Text = (string)findme;


            tmpRange.Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

            object start = tmpRange.Start;
            object end = tmpRange.End;


            List<User> users = GetDummyUserData();
            int noOfRows = users.Count + 1;
            int noOfColumns = 5;
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table table = doc.Tables.Add(doc.Range(ref start, ref end), noOfRows, noOfColumns, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

            AddColumnHeaders(ref table);
            for (int i = 1; i <= users.Count; i++)
            {
                table.Rows[i + 1].Cells[1].Range.Text = users[i - 1].FirstName;
                table.Rows[i + 1].Cells[2].Range.Text = users[i - 1].LastName;
                table.Rows[i + 1].Cells[3].Range.Text = users[i - 1].Email;
                table.Rows[i + 1].Cells[4].Range.Text = users[i - 1].Address;
                table.Rows[i + 1].Cells[5].Range.Text = users[i - 1].Pincode.ToString();
            }
            table.set_Style("Colorful List");



        }
```

Comment: Post some code; otherwise it is just guessing.

Comment: Is this still an issue?  What is it about your current code that doesn't work?